# AngularJS custom validation $setValidity

Tags: angularjs

Consider this runnable example: http://plnkr.co/edit/1BfO7KkHeMD3EpsULNGP?p=preview

```html
<html ng-app='app'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('pwCheck', [function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck; 
      elem.add(firstPassword).on('keyup', function () { 
          var v = elem.val()===$(firstPassword).val();
          console.log(v);
          ctrl.$setValidity('pwcheck', v); 
      });
    }
  }
}]);
</script> 
<form name="form">
<input type="text" id="pw1" name="pw1" ng-model="pw1Model">
<input type="text" name="pw2" pw-check="pw1" ng-model="pw2Model">
Valid:  {{form.pw2.$valid}}
<pre>{{form.pw2 |json}}</pre>
</form>
```

Write a character i one of the fields, and see that the validity is not updated until the second character is written in. The validity is not correct if you test to copy/paste etc. But the correct value v is logged. Why is the model not changed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `$setValidity` into $timeout

```
$timeout(function() {
   ctrl.$setValidity('pwcheck', v);
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OSuHBgtReDoCGWi03Cc8?p=preview

I assume that there is some conflict with the `$setValidity` call of angular native `input` directive.
Wrapping this call into `$timeout` makes it possible to avoid this conflict.

Comment: Is it similar to nextTick()?

Comment: Yes. To be more exact $setValidity call will be queued.